# How to resize ScrollView when keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create this post feature which would allow you to insert text as well as images (similar to Note app on iOS devices). However, I can't figure out how to move or resize my ScrollView when the keyboard appears when I press on the light-grey area (it's a text view field), so the grey area would resize and the add button would move above the keyboard when it appears.

```
//  PostViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Martynas on 09/12/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Martynas. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class PostViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var titleTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var contentTextField: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var Menu: UIView!

@IBAction func hideKeyboardWhenSwippedDown(_ sender: Any) {
    contentTextField.endEditing(true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Hide keyboard when...
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() // ...press anywhere outside the keyboard

    self.titleTextField.delegate = self
    self.contentTextField.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
        if let title = titleTextField.text {
            if let content = contentTextField.text {
                let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                    "uid": uid,
                    "title": title,
                    "content": content
                ]

                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)

            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: Any) {

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == contentTextField {
        ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
    } else {
        return
    }

}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == contentTextField {
        ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 250), animated: true)
    } else {
        return
    }
}

// Hide keyboard when user presses 'return' key on the keyboard...
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    titleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
    }
}
```

This is the Controller View:

[image: Controller View]

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the `keyboardDidShow/Hide` notification and adjust the scroll view's height accordingly. The `keyboardDidShow` notification `userInfo` contains the keyboard's frame and therefore height.

Presuming your scroll view has a constraint at the bottom of the super view, you can make it an `IBOutlet` and animate it's constant to the height of the keyboard and back to 0 when the keyboard show and hide notifications are fired respectively.